How does Verilog handle posedge vs VHDL's rising_edge()?
I have been learning Verilog for a class I am taking and ran across something a bit strange to me.  If I were to write a DFF in VHDL (which I am more used to), I would do something like:
DFF : process(CLK, RESET_N)
begin

    if RESET_N = '0' then
        Q <= '0';
    elsif rising_edge(CLK) then
        Q <= D;
    end if;

end process DFF;

I tried a similar approach in Verilog:
always @ (clk, reset_n) begin

    if(reset_n == 0) begin
        q = 0;
    end else if(posedge clk) begin
        q = d;
    end

end

However when doing this, I get a compile error - near "posedge": syntax error, unexpected posedge.  I'm using Questasim as my simulator.
My question is, how does Verilog handle posedge and how does it differ from VHDL's rising_edge?  Can I only use posedge in Verilog inside of the sensitivity list for the always block?

Pretty much.  You want always @ (posedge clk) and you check the reset signal in the block.

posedge is technically an 'event expression' in Verilog. It's not an expression. The grammar for the if statement is if(expression), so you're out of luck.
The Verilog and VHDL versions are subtly different. rising_edge is a function which is defined in std_logic_1164. Basically, if a signal was 0 or L, and is now 1 or H, you have a rising edge. Verilog's posedge is defined by the LRM and includes x and z. See p133 of the 2005 LRM, but note that 0 to z, for example, is a posedge.
You can find the flip-flop equivalents (and lots of other Verilog/VHDL equivalents) here.
Edit: I've just read this answer again and realised that it's rather simplistic. It is technically what you asked for, but your two examples are fundamentally different. The VHDL one you're used to works because VHDL keeps an event history for signals. The process is run because CLK changed (had an event on it). In the body of the process, your simulator knows that CLK had an event in the current delta, so rising_edge returns true.
The Verilog version is very different; Verilog doesn't have signal attributes such as 'event and 'last_value. By the time you've got to the posedge Verilog no longer knows why it's in the 'process', so you're stuck with looking at signal values. IOW, the Verilog version doesn't work for multiple reasons.
